# How can I get a string from a class? (Android studio) abbyy OCR recognition

Tags: android, class, android-studio, ocr, abbyy

I am very new to Android and Java, but I want to modify a little bit this sample.

https://github.com/abbyysdk/RTR-SDK.Android/tree/master/sample-textcapture

I want to use/store what the OCR recognizes as a variable or as a string.

I think it's the **lines** class the information I want to get and is in this part of the code.

```
public void onFrameProcessed( ITextCaptureService.TextLine[] lines,
        ITextCaptureService.ResultStabilityStatus resultStatus, ITextCaptureService.Warning warning )
    {
        // Frame has been processed. Here we process recognition results. In this sample we
        // stop when we get stable result. This callback may continue being called for some time
        // even after the service has been stopped while the calls queued to this thread (UI thread)
        // are being processed. Just ignore these calls:
        if( !stableResultHasBeenReached ) {
            if( resultStatus.ordinal() >= 3 ) {
                // The result is stable enough to show something to the user
                surfaceViewWithOverlay.setLines( lines, resultStatus );

            } else {
                // The result is not stable. Show nothing
                surfaceViewWithOverlay.setLines( null, ITextCaptureService.ResultStabilityStatus.NotReady );
            }

            // Show the warning from the service if any. The warnings are intended for the user
            // to take some action (zooming in, checking recognition language, etc.)
            warningTextView.setText( warning != null ? warning.name() : "" );

            if( resultStatus == ITextCaptureService.ResultStabilityStatus.Stable ) {
                // Stable result has been reached. Stop the service
                stopRecognition();
                stableResultHasBeenReached = true;

                // Show result to the user. In this sample we whiten screen background and play
                // the same sound that is used for pressing buttons
                surfaceViewWithOverlay.setFillBackground( true );
                startButton.playSoundEffect( android.view.SoundEffectConstants.CLICK );
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the documentation for the `ITextCaptureService.TextLine` class reveals that the `Text` attribute is a `String` containing the recognized text. All you have to do is iterate over each of the `lines` to get the text. Something like:

```
String recognizedText = "";
foreach(ITextCaptureService.TextLine line : lines) {
   recognizedText += line.Text;
}

/* do something with recognizedText */
```

In the case of your sample:

```
public void onFrameProcessed( ITextCaptureService.TextLine[] lines,
    ITextCaptureService.ResultStabilityStatus resultStatus, ITextCaptureService.Warning warning )
{
   ...
        if( resultStatus == ITextCaptureService.ResultStabilityStatus.Stable) {
            // Stable result has been reached. Stop the service
            stopRecognition();
            stableResultHasBeenReached = true;

            String recognizedText = "";
            foreach(ITextCaptureService.TextLine line : lines) {
                   recognizedText += line.Text;
            }

             /* do something with recognizedText */

        }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Justin! First of all thank you for answering my question! I don't need to recognize many lines, it's just one. In the other hand, When I try to assign the lines.text value to a String, I get the error "Cannot resolve symbol lines" As you see, I am very newbie in this Android/Java things.

Comment: @wsNico I updated my answer to show it in relation to your sample. The `...` are placeholders to the rest of the sample unrelated to your question.